# Error when trying to load view in my_controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Consider my code:

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function _displayPage($page, $data = array()) {
        $this->load->view('structure/header', $data);
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
        $this->load->view('structure/footer', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

page.php

```
<?php
    class Page extends MY_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();  
        }   

        function index() {
            $data['content'] = array('title'=>'hello world');
            $this->_displayPage('home', $data); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Upon loading my page on my browser, I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Page::$view
Filename: libraries/MY_Controller.php
Line Number: 11
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you're not using the CI framework the way it is ment to be used. What are you trying to achieve? A plain controller displaying a view file?

Comment: I want to be able to have a header and footer view file in each page but i dont really want to include the header and footer file in every page view i create

Comment: yea he just trying to create a generic controller  for all his views, try doing `parent::load->view('structure/header', $data);` instead.

Comment: No problem, I've added the answer to the posts s you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Why are you redefining `__construct()` if you just call the parent method within it?  This is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your library `My_Controller` you should be using the `parent` keyword instead of $this.

your code should look like so:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function _displayPage($page, $data = array())
    {
        parent::load->view('structure/header', $data);
        parent::load->view($page, $data);
        parent::load->view('structure/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate. I've got tons of instances of `$this` in my `MY_Controller` class, including the explicit calling of `$this->load->view(...)`

Comment: this is not a an action controller such as `index` this class is an extention of the base controller, so you then go: `class index extends MY_Controller`, this answer is correct if you see the OP Comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish correctly, you're wanting to setup a template that includes your header view and footer view, but without calling header and footer views for each controller you use throughout your application. Here's what I've done to accomplish this.

First, create a new folder under your views, for this example we'll call it 'includes'. Inside the newly created includes folder, create three files, header.php, footer.php and template.php. Setup your header and footer appropriately and then edit your template.php to look as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->load->view('includes/univ_header'); ?>

<?php echo $this->load->view($main_content); ?>

<?php echo $this->load->view('includes/univ_footer'); ?>
```

Now, from your controller you can define what view you would like to set as your 'main_content'. For example, if you have home.php in your views folder and you want to wrap it with your header and footer you would do so in your controller as follows:

```
function index() {
        $data['content'] = array('title'=>'hello world');
        $data['main_content'] = 'home';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
```

Hope this helps!