# Error When Loading View in My_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to implement the solution referenced at:

[Error when trying to load view in my_controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708639/error-when-trying-to-load-view-in-my-controller)

Don't know why, but Aptana indicates a syntax error on my line:

```
parent::load->view('common/header_out');
```

...which is seconded by the interpreter when I execute:  "unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR"

EDIT:  Previously I tried using:

```
$this->load->view('common/header_out');
```

...which generated the following errors:

> Warning: include(application/errors/error_php.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or >directory in /home/uom2/www/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 167
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'application/errors/error_php.php' for inclusion >(include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/uom2/www/system/core/Exceptions.php on >line 167

I am using CI 2.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

application/core/Uom_Controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Uom_Controller  extends CI_Controller
{

  public   $data = array();  // Array to store data - passed to views.
 protected  $view_path = null;  // Here to overide the view path if n
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    protected function check_session()
    {
        //Here goes your function
    }

 protected function render() {


      $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
  $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';

      parent::load->view('common/header_out');
      parent::load->->view('home/home', $data);
      parent::load->->view('common/foot');

echo "view rendered:  ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');



}

}
```

controllers/home/home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home   extends Uom_Controller  {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

      // Set the view path manually for this method.
      $this->view_path = 'home/home.php';

    }


    function __destruct() {
        $this->render();
    }


    public function index()
    {
        echo "home updated";
        
    }


    public function out()
    {
        echo "logout";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $this->view_path;
        echo "<br>";
        
    }


}
```

obviously the intention is similiar to the SO post at the top of this post:  I want the $this->render(); to be called and render my page header, body, and footer.

(My next task is to add the authentication check to this MY_Controller pattern, so I am hoping that whaever solution works for calling views also works on models.

Thanks everyone and I really have spent hours trying to find a solution to this beforw once again turning to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.  here is the problem:

```
function __destruct() {
  $this->render();
}
```

According to a remark by Phil Surgeon on [here](http://__destruct%20does%20not%20work%20as%20expected%20due%20to%20the%20way%20everything%20is%20inherited.)

> __destruct does not work as expected due to the way everything is
>   inherited.

...and further down the page, a more detailed explanation that seems to make sense:

> The problem is that the controller IS the CI superobject, once you
>   destroy that, you lose all access to CI. And you don’t have any
>   control over the destruct process, so you don’t know what is still
>   accessable, and what isn’t.
>
> Using __destruct() for anything other than cleanup actions for
>   destruction of the current object is a very bad idea…

The short answer is that things work so long as you are not calling a method from the extended class from "_destruct".

Hopes this helps someone else.

Comment: It seems strange that you've only ever accepted 3 answers, not even your own! The feature is there for good reason. Never-mind the frustration some people may feel when they put effort into writing the perfect answer just to have it languish.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are calling parent::load->view instead of $this->load->view

Comment: Sorry, in my original post I failed to mention that I had started out that way and the resulting errors were what led to my discovering the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708639/error-when-trying-to-load-view-in-my-controller